# Does printf() set errno upon failure?

Tags: c, io, printf, errno

Does `printf()` set `errno` to an appropriate value apart from just returning '*a negative value*' upon failure ?

I can't seem to find man pages that say anything about this on Google .

Close this question if it's a duplicate. Link the answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, on any POSIX system, but not necessarily in any ISO C implementation.

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html:

> If an output error was encountered, these functions shall return a negative value **and set errno to indicate the error.**

The bolded part is marked as an extension to ISO C.

Comment: Okay, thankee, **BUT** what about `scanf` ? is it setting `errno` also only for POSIX-confirming systems ?

Comment: Yes, the same. In ISO C, only a limited set of functions are required to set `errno` and only a limited set of `errno` values are known.

Comment: Oh.. when someone says '*C89*' or '*C99*' , do they mean ISO C ? And when K&R 2nd edition says '*ANSI C*' does it also mean ISO C ?

Comment: I am meaning C99, and that's what I have checked, but I really don't think that they have added (or plan to add) extensive errno handling spec to newer versions of the C standard.